# String.format() com erro

Tags: java, android, string

Preciso formatar a seguinte string com o respectivo parâmetro, porém esta gerando o seguinte erro:

> Caused by: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %d can't format
>   java.lang.String arguments

```
private static final String URL_HOST = "http://xxxx.com/";    
private static final String URL_VERIFICA_ATUALIZACAO = "aaaa/%d";
String url = String.format(URL_HOST + URL_VERIFICA_ATUALIZACAO, ultimaConfiguracao.getUltima_atualizacao()); //retorna um Long (valor zero)
```

Propriedade:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG, canBeNull = false, defaultValue = "0")
private long ultima_atualizacao;

public long getUltima_atualizacao() {
        return ultima_atualizacao;
    }

public void setUltima_atualizacao(long ultima_atualizacao) {
        this.ultima_atualizacao = ultima_atualizacao;
    }
```

Comment: Certeza que o erro é nessa linha msm? Fiz um teste aqui e não consigo imaginar o que pode estar causando o erro. Experimenta fazer um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Math estou fazendo isto dentro de um método assíncrono, que até agora estava gerando outros erros, porém o último é este... (sou inexperiente em Android), criei o código inteiro de uma classe necessária e agora estou testando, não creio que seja um bug do Android Studio acusar o erro na linha errada...

Comment: Amigo, o erro persiste? Se sim, eu estou reproduzindo o erro aqui, e ele está retornando normal quando eu utilizo um `Long`, ou `Int`, mas o erro está mesmo quando é `String`... O que essa parte define `defaultValue = "0"` na anotação em cima da propriedade?

Comment: @GustavoCinque ele diz que o valor padrão seja zero, eu consegui resolver o problema mas não entendi por que ele ocorre, eu fiz o teste e troquei por string, mas ficou estranho pois na verdade é um Long... vai entender?

Comment: Hm... Pra mim quando utilizo `String` é quando dá erro. Eu pensei que esse `defaultValue = "0"` define o valor do Long no banco como Character, ou algo assim, mas acredito que não.

Comment: Ele apenas seta o valor padrão pra zero do long.